# Where do I purchase a fly with the collagen tagged?

Tags: genetics, histology

Where can I purchase a fly with tagged collagen?  My senior undergraduate research paper is observing the collagen in larvae with normal diet compared to larvae with an experimental diet.  I need flies that have the protein tagged so I can observe the collagen under a fluorescent microscope.  Instead of using an expensive antibody (my budget is $300) to tag the protein, my advisor suggested purchasing stock flies that already have the tagged protein.

Comment: try bloomington (http://flystocks.bio.indiana.edu) if you work with Drosophila.

Answer (score 3):

There are some more places other than what Bez has already mentioned.

See [here](http://flybase.org/wiki/FlyBase:Stock_Collections).

However, tagging collagen may be a problem. Collagen undergoes a lot of post-translational modifications including hydroxylation and end clipping. It forms a unique structure (triplex) and adding tags may compromise its structural integrity. You can try [Masson's trichome stain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masson%27s_trichrome_stain) instead, which is used to stain collagen — a very cheap alternative.